# Updated to MacTeX 2015 and TeXstudio 2.10.4: cref and biblatex no longer includes the float label or cite key in code suggestions

Tags: texstudio, mactex, auto-completion

I just recently updated to MacTeX 2015. With the 2014 version, I could type \cref, and TeXstudio would suggest a list of all labels used in the document, making cross-referencing easy. The same with BibLaTeX: the cite keys in the included bib file would be suggested, so that I easily could choose which source to cite while typing. Now I have to type the table/figure label manually, and look up the cite keys manually. This make writing much less efficient.

I am not sure if this is an issue with the MacTeX distribution, or with the TeXstudio editor.

Comment: It's almost certainly related to the Texstudio update you performed. Did you check if re-running BibTeX solves the problem?

Comment: From 2.10.0 on there are substantial changes to the internal parser in TeXstudio, so I would not exclude that there is a bug. However, it works for me. My first guess would be that you are having a multifile document and did not open the other files containing the labels or the inclusion of the bib file. In that case TXS cannot know about labels. If this doesn't solve your problem you may open an issue in the TeXstudio bug tracker. Make sure to include a minimal working example to demonstrate the effect.

Comment: No, I am writing everything inside the one .tex file. I just realized that the usual "label" dropdown menu in the panel (under to the "Bibliography" one) is not showing. Maybe that is why TeXstudio does not find the labels?

Comment: @TimHoffmann Issue opened at SourceForge.